# Why am I getting ugly curly brackets around my text in the label widget? - Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, curly-brackets

I'm getting curly brackets around the text in my label widget. The output is `{Total tries: 0}` instead of `Total tries: 0`.

Here is a short version of my code:

```
class Cell:
    def check(self):
        mem.tries += 1
        mem.update_tries()

class Memory(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super(Memory, self).__init__(master)
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()
        self.tries = 0

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.label = Label(self)
        self.label["text"] = "Total tries: 0",
        self.label["font"] = ("Helvetica", 11, "italic")
        self.label.grid(row = 7, columnspan = 7, pady = 5)

    def update_tries(self):
        self.label["text"] = "Total tries: " + str(self.tries)

root = Tk()
root.title("Memory")
root.geometry("365x355")
mem = Memory(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
self.label["text"] = "Total tries: 0",
```

There is a comma at the end of the line. The comma changes the value being assigned to `self.label["text"]` from a string to a tuple. Remove the comma, and the curly braces get removed.

Comment: Where can I find documentation on `self.label["text"]`? I've only known about the `textvariable/StringVar` way.

Comment: I learnt about "self.label["text"]" in the book "Python programming for the absolute beginner - third edition"

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why that happens; however, when I've used Tkinter, I've always done text updates either with a `StringVar` or using the `config` method.  [Here's](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/label.htm)  a page with some examples.

Example using a `StringVar`:

```
# in class Memory

def create_widgets(self):
  self.labelText = StringVar()
  self.label = Label(self, textvariable = self.labelText)
  ... rest of method ...

def update_tries(self):
  self.labelText.set("Total tries: " + str(self.tries))
```

Comment: I couldn't get it to work...
Thanks for the link to that page though :)

Comment: I still got the curly brackets. The problem is solved now. Thanks for your help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem but none of these solutions worked for me. For anyone in the future that struggles with this, I get an error on text that contains a space in such as `"Health and Fitness"` which would be printed as `{Health and Fitness}`.

For me, the solution was to **not** instantiate the labels such as:

```
score = 25
tk.Label(container, text=("Health and Fitness",score)).pack()
```

But rather, like **this**:

```
toPrint = "Health and Fitness" + str(score)
tk.Label(container, text=toPrint).pack()
```